# How to choose between two values using 'or' in matlab?

Tags: matlab, find, logic, cell

I have the following code :

```
a = cell(4,1);
a{1} = [5 3 0 0];
a{2} = [0 3 5 0];
a{3} = [1 3 0 0];
a{4} = [0 3 2 0];

arrayind = 2;

b = a(cellfun(@(x)x(arrayind) == 1,a));
b{:}
```

How can I achieve this when an IF statement is used :

```
if r>2
b = a(cellfun(@(x)x(arrayind) == (1 | 2 | 3),a));
end
```

Basically saying, find 1, if not there then 2, if not there then 3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ismember` could perhaps be what you are looking for.
Replacing the equality operator with `ismember` as follows:

```
a = cell(4,1);
a{1} = [5 3 0 0];
a{2} = [0 3 5 0];
a{3} = [1 3 0 0];
a{4} = [0 3 2 0];
arrayind = 1;
b = a(cellfun(@(x) ismember(x(arrayind), [1 5]), a));
```

would yield `b = a([1, 3])`

Comment: Your code really helped me but im facing a new problem. If you have time please check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576345/how-to-choose-identical-values-in-a-cell-array-using-matlab