# How to choose identical values in a cell array with constraints using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, compare, constraints, combinations

If I have a 4x1 Cell structure with that represents `a=[A1 A2 A3 A4]` :

```
a=cell(4,1)
a{1}=[1 3 1 0]
a{2}=[3 3 3 3]
a{3}=[3 2 3 2]
a{4}=[3 3 3 2]

B=[1 1 1 2]; %priority
```

**I would like to do the following :**

Pick cells that correspond to priority `B=[1 1 1 2]` (where `B=1` is highest priority and `A=3`)
Which means, find any cell that begins with [3 3 3 #], where all their priority is 1's in `B`.

ideal answer should be :     `a{2}`=`[3 3 3 3]` and `a{4}` = `[3,3,3,2]`

---

My try is to add this :

```
[P arrayind]=min(B) % problem is that arrayind return index=1 only .. not all indices
if P==1
   arrayindex = 1:4 ; %look at each index of the array
   c = a(cellfun(@(x) ismember(x(arrayindex), 3), a));
end
```

However this gives me an error stating :

```
Error using cellfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.
```

By adjusting the code to accommodate this error :

```
c = a(cellfun(@(x) ismember(x(arrayindex), 3), a,'UniformOutput',false));

I get this error :

Error using subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.
```

And now I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: did you try to edit the `cellfun` line according to the error? that is `cellfun(@(x) ... ,'UniformOutput', false);`

Comment: @natan Yes, I should have mentioned that. Updating question

Comment: What value(s) are you expecting for c after running this code?

Comment: @wakjah I updated the question so it's clearer..The results should be `a{2}` and `a{4}`

Comment: @NLed try: `[val ind] = max(cellfun(@(x) length(find(ismember(x(arrayindex), 3))), a)); b = a(ind);`. This will give the cell array with the highest number of 3s.

Comment: @jucestain Thank you for replying, but I want `all` results that have [3 3 3 %], where % can be anything .. this is due to priority B=[1 1 1 2] .. does this make sense ? Updated question to clarify this point

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your problem exactly, but if the "`% problem is that arrayind return index=1 only .. not all indices`", you could simply compute arrayind as `arrayind = find(B==min(B));`.

Comment: RoneyMichael Thank you for replying. However I still get Error using cellfun Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1. Set 'UniformOutput' to false. Although it DOES point out which indices have highest priorities.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but are you looking to get the locations where `a` attains maximum when the priority of `B` is highest(i.e., 1)?

Comment: @RoneyMichael Yes, but also store cells that correspond to these values in `c`. In which case `a{2}` and `a{4}` are going to be stored in c. So using your code, it returns `arrayindex = 1     2     3` , so the code will then check indices `1 2 3` of each cell for `3` such that `a=[3 3 3 #]` .. hope this makes sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be an elegant answer, but it is effective:

```
%The input cell array.
a = cell(4,1);
a{1} = [1 3 1 0];
a{2} = [3 3 3 3];
a{3} = [3 2 3 2];
a{4} = [3 3 3 2];

%The input priority array.
B = [1 1 1 2];

%The output cell array: preallocated for efficiency.
c = cell(size(a));

j = 1;
for i = 1:size(a,1)
%For each i
    if(all(((cell2mat(a(i))==3)&(B==1))==(B==1)))
    %"cell2mat" converts the cell arrays into easily comparable number arrays.
    %"X==Y" for matrices of the same size, will give you a result matrix of the same size with 1 where the values are equal and 0 elsewhere.
    %Thus, "cell2mat(a(i))==3" would compare the number matrices represented by "a{i}" with "3".
    %"(cell2mat(a(i))==3)&(B==1)" would do a logical AND operation with "B==1", that is, "[1 1 1 0]".
    %In short, since you want whereever "a{i}" is 3 when "B" is 1, we want those "a{i}" where the comparison stated above is the same as "B==1".
    %If the result array is the same as "B=1", we get "[1 1 1 1]" as the result of the comparison "((cell2mat(a(i))==3)&(B==1))==(B==1)".
    %The function "all" checks whether the input to it is completely non-zero: here if we get a "[1 1 1 1]" "all" will give us 1, else 0.
        c{j} = a{i};
        %Insert result array into "c" when condition is satisfied.

        j = j + 1;
        %Increment the index of "c".
    end
end


c = c(1:j-1);
%Truncate unused rows of "c".

cell2mat(c)
%Displays the value of "c" as computed.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Can you please tell me how the code is working ? I would like to learn rather than just use the code blindly.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll add comments to the answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would this also work if I want to check for more values ?? For example, if `B=2`, then check for `(2 or 3)` rather than just 3. Do I only need to change

Comment: If you want it to work for both `B=2` and `B=3`, replace `B==1` with `(B==1) | (B==2)` or `(B==1) + (B==2)`. This will make it treat `2` the same way it treats `3`.

Comment: Yes. I'm off for now. If you have any more doubts, leave them as comments below; I'll check back here later.